# Dimension and measure

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

We have the well known fact that a $n-1$ dimensional immersed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of zero Lebesgue measure (a null set).

To what extend does this generalize to the broader concept of topological dimension. I.e., is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with *covering dimension* $ \leq n-1$ a null set? Is a subspace of *inductive dimension* $\leq n-1$ a null set? If not, do the claims hold under additional restrictions on the subspace in question, i.e. closed / compact etc.